# fprintf returns success but can't write to an existing file

Tags: c, file, io, stream, printf

In my code fprintf returns successfully by returning the number of bytes written in STREAM, but in the actual file the string I wrote is not there.

Comment: Did you `fclose()` the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output is probably just buffered.  Try closing the file using close() or call fflush() on the stream to force the string to the file.

Comment: That does _not_ force the data out of memory, for that you need fsync.